# Setting the "Enable3D" property of "ChartArea" in Code behind for StackedColumn charts

Tags: c#, charts, 3d, stacked

I created a StackedColumn chart using the built in .NET 4.0 controls. 
The charts are coming out properly. 
I want to make it look 3-D though. 
I am able to do that by using XAML. But I am unable to do the same using code behind.

Please see my code behind. I have a Chart, and a ChartArea. I saw that the code to enable 3-D is as follows:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
```

But I get an error at Runtime as follows:
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

I also tried using the following options (where cArea is the instance of ChartArea) :

```
cArea.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;

Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;

Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
```

Is there any difference in where I set these properties. I tried all the 3 above statements before I add the Chart1 element.

The code behind I use is :

```
        Chart1.Series.Clear();
        Chart1.ChartAreas.Clear();

        ChartArea cArea = new ChartArea("Default");
        Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(cArea);

        // ABLE TO USE cArea to change properties.... !!!
        cArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = +80;
        cArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
        cArea.BackColor = Color.Beige;



        foreach (var g in groups)
        {
            Series s1 = new Series(g.Key);
            Chart1.Series.Add(s1);

            s1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
            s1["PointWidth"] = "0.7";
            foreach (var m in g)
            {
                s1.Points.AddXY(m.Category, m.Count);
            }
            s1.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
            s1.ToolTip = "#VALY";
        }


        this.Controls.Add(Chart1);
```

The XAML is :

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" ImageLocation="~/FolderLoc/Chart_#SEQ(1000,0)"     ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation" ImageType="Png" >
</asp:Chart>
```

I am however able to use the cArea to change other properties as part of my chart as shown in the code:

```
// ABLE TO USE cArea to change properties.... !!!
cArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = +80;
cArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
cArea.BackColor = Color.Beige;
```

When using Static data, I am able to set the "Enable3D" to TRUE with the XAML as :

```
   <chartareas>
       <asp:ChartArea Name="Default">
           <Area3DStyle Enable3D="True" />
       </asp:ChartArea>
   </chartareas>
```

Can you please tell me how to make the chart 3-D enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to try:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;

Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already tried these out. It is not working. I still get teh same "Index error"

Comment: The error is not coming from that line or you have really messed up your chart.  If I drop a chart on a form and do nothing with it I can execute this line: chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;

Comment: Yeah ! Looks like it is something to do with the data I am trying to populate. When I changed the data that I am trying to render with some dummy data it worked.                                                                             The data I am rendering has some parts of the stacked-chart which are empty.--> i.e Some of the categories don't always have count of bugs=ZERO. I think that is what is causing the issue. What can I do to ensure that even if there is no data(i.e CRITICAL bugs for a category=ZERO), how do I handle this case?

Answer (score 0):

You have empty data in the X axis.  Use AlignDataPointsByAxis to fix this.